# Django decimal field fails to store floating numbers that should be ok

Tags: python, django, floating-point, decimal, rounding

In a django project I'm trying to store a calculated decimal value, but it fails for some strange reason. My model looks something like:

```
class FancyModel(models.Model):
  fancy_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
```

Sometimes, rather often actually, it crashes on save:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: myapp_fancy_model`

which I found out after some digging was caused by this validation:

`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'fancy_field': ['Ensure that there are no more than 2 decimal places.']}`

I've dumped the values of the actual model, and it seems ok to me:

`{'fancy_field': 3.26 }`

I cannot see how this would fail. Sometimes it works fine, other times it crashes. I've tried to use the round-method, like:

`model_instance.fancy_model = round(floating_value, 2)`
but it still fails.

Comment: Can you share a full traceback and your view/function/code that triggers the error?

Comment: Maybe the issue is of using `float` instead of `Decimal`? Had you tried to wrap `fancy_field` values onto `Decimal(float_value)`?

Answer (score 1):

After commenting out all the code, then adding one after one line back in, I discovered that the error wasn't caused by the decimalfield at all, but a PositiveIntegerField that got a negative value. The model.full_clean() never mentioned the PositiveIntegerField at all, so this is really weird. That's a few hours I won't get back :-/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the decimal_places param passed from 3 to 2

Comment: I've tried that. Tried max_digits to 30 and decimal_places to 15. Nothing helps.